# configure DOSGi with UDP

Tags: osgi, ipojo, dosgi

I use DOSGi to connect two OSGi components (iPOJO components) over local network.
I configured it with either SOAP or RESTful-JAX RS. However, both use TCP for communication (i saw this in Wireshark).

Now, i would like to configure SOAP or RESTful-JAX RS with UDP. How can i do that?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Apache CXF DOSGI implementation: [Given how CXF can use UDP as a transport](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/udp-transport.html), it looks simple enough to use a udp URL as your "org.apache.cxf.ws.address" when creating your distributed service.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your response.
I implemented an application including a server component and a client component 
as indicated by 
[Using Distributed Services with iPOJO](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-gettingstarted/apache-felix-ipojo-dosgi.html).

However, it uses TCP for client-server communication

I tried to declare the server with the "org.apache.cxf.ws.address" property with UDP as "udp://localhost:9090/service".

Example:

```
<property name="service.exported.interfaces" value="*" />
<property name="service.exported.configs" value="org.apache.cxf.ws" /> 
<property name="org.apache.cxf.ws.address" value="udp://localhost:9090/service" />
```

However, i received an error:

```
Unknown protocol: udp
```

I'm using the package cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution-1.1.jar for client-server communication 
Could you please give me some advices?